# Turing Machine vs Universal Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines

I am a computer science student and at the moment I am starting a new subject called models of computing.

I am trying to understand what is the difference between a Turing Machine and an Universal Turing Machine.

For what I understand a Turing Machine can be compared to a program that runs on our computer and an universal Turing machine can be compared to a computer, that can run any program.

So, a universal Turing machine can handle various Turing machines?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

A UTM is a TM that get code of a TM and its input and return the output of the TM on the input as its output. See details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine):

> a universal Turing machine (UTM) is a Turing machine that can simulate an arbitrary Turing machine on arbitrary input. The universal machine essentially achieves this by reading both the description of the machine to be simulated as well as the input thereof from its own tape

Answer (score 1):

By the Church Turing Thesis, a TM can represent any computable algorithm in the world, including your own Python program. 
So if a Python program can take as input an encoding of a 'TM' and run it, then there exists a TM (in fact a UTM) that can do exactly this. 
You can try to write your own UTM in Python to simulate an TM, with a lot of string parsing functions.